# windows phone 8 development: HTML5/CSS/Javascript with XAML

Tags: html

i'm a new to develop mobile application.

I need to do windows phone 8 apps using HTML5 for my final year project. But at the same time i would want to include the panorama view that is available on the windows phone 8 template.

Is it possible to combine them? what i mean by combining is the login page for the application is HTML page and when the user login, it direct them to the panorama view and on the panorama view it display the HTML5 content.

As i have done using XAML/C# for the panorama view but the criteria is to use HTML5 and at the same time i wanted to have that panorama view so i'm stuck on doing the project for 1 week due to searching for all the details but yet find any.

I need advise from you guys... i don't need you guys to write or give me any code. I just need guidelines on where should i look at for knowledge. I hope you guys help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com) and this Jquery plugin for supporting the [panorama view](https://github.com/grohman/js-panorama).

Comment: Hi Atropo, thanks for giving me advice... I would like to know is it possible to do from scratch without 3rd party stuff...